# Two 'Homebrew' on my mac; one in opt and one in local. How do I delete one?

Tags: homebrew, apple-m1

I bought a new Mac Studio to replace my old (2013) Mac Pro.  I used Homebrew for programming for school; I'm over 75 but I'm going to school (ece) for fun.  Thinking it would be a good idea to install a Homebrew for the Apple chipset, I installed Homebrew.  But instead of overwriting my old version, it installed a new version in /opt .  The old was in /usr/local/bin .  How do I delete the old install?  Somehow I think having two 'brew's is not a god idea.

I've tried nothing so far.  I don't think rmdir -pv on /usr/local/bin/brew would be sufficient.  Especially as I don't know where Homebrew store everything and I might end up deleting something I need and don't know I need it.

Comment: Hi LarryS ... can you say a little more about the purpose for installing brew on your m1?  Are you planning on continuing programming?  You now have two brews on your system, which is not all bad ... I have two on purpose.  Reason is that m1 brew will install m1 apps; "old" brew will install intel apps.  You *probably* only want m1 brew, but depends on purpose ...

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  Yes, I will continue to code; need in some classes.  Also for fun.  I'm wondering about if the 'brew' will interfere with hone another.  Further, maintaining two 'brew'?

Comment: To clarify: Are you saying you managed to install *non-M1* homebrew under /usr/local/bin on your M1 mac? Maybe refer to the homebrew uninstaller script: https://github.com/homebrew/install#uninstall-homebrew

Comment: No, the 'first' Homebrew was installed at "/usr/local/bin/brew"a few years ago on my MacPro 2013.  The 'second' Homebrew was installed per Apple ?requirements? and is in "/opt/homebrew".  I did not realize this would happen.

Answer (score 10):

The Homebrew installation under `/usr/local` is for Intel and the installation under `/opt/homebrew` is for M1.

If you want to remove the Intel installation, you can download the [official uninstall script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Homebrew/install/HEAD/uninstall.sh). Make it executable with:

```
chmod +x uninstall.sh
```

and run it on the Intel installation with:

```
./uninstall.sh --path=/usr/local
```